# Pacemaker/Corosync: how to emergency-shutdown all resources (VMs qemu/kvm)

Tags: high-availability, failovercluster, redundancy

Good morning everyone -

Running a 6 node **Pacemaker/Corosync** cluster with lots of productive *qemu/kvm* VMs on it, we were wondering how to best do an "**emergency shutdown**" of the whole lot, ie. when the UPS signals "AC fail" and "low battery".
After reading docs and forums, we are still not sure about the following:

1. is there a way of addressing *all* running resources at once we did not see? Neither `pcs resource disable --all` nor `pcs resource disable \*` works...
2. hence: how to safely get a (parse-able) list of resources running? Am I supposed to really parse the output of `pcs resource` ...?
3. will `pcs cluster stop --all` shut down (or at least *try to*) all resources beforehand (that is to mean: runs `pcs resource disable ...` on all resources)? Or is it rather a `kill -9` to all resources?

Thanks for all enlightenment!

Comment: ... forgot to say that we've got foisted with the cluster which was set up by someone else, and have no test environment...

Answer (score 1):

i'm currently facing the same problem. We have a two node cluster with about 20 qemu/kvm vm's. A power outtage a short while ago showed me that our cluster shutdown concept does not work. I'm asking the same question as you in the pacemaker mailing list. Here is the archive: https://lists.clusterlabs.org/pipermail/users/2022-February/thread.html , it seems to be up t odate.

Bernd